# ColdFusion: invalid source file specified

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-9

I am creating a local project. I have a Word doc file with name "Maßnahme3" (these are German characters). I want to convert this to a PDF file and I am trying to do this by using the `<cfdocument>` tag. But ColdFusion is throwing the following error:

> Invalid source C:\\Maßnahme3.doc specified

Anyone have an idea why this is not working?

Comment: have you tried c:\ ?

Comment: Yes I have tried "c:\"but not working.

Comment: What is the actual filename on disk? That character may be getting changed. Try running `<cfdirectory action="list" directory="C:\" recurse="false" name="myList">` and then `<cfdump var="#myList#">` to see what the filename looks like.

Comment: Please add the line of code that is causing the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Place the following 2 lines of code at the top of your ColdFusion page. They let ColdFusion know how to interprete the symbols.

```
<cfprocessingdirective pageEncoding="UTF-8">
<cfset setLocale("German (Standard)")>
```

Comment: Yes this solution worked for me. But can we set multiple locale. Suppose I have file with some chinese characters too then what will happen.

Comment: Locale implies, amongst others, language and notation. You can only use one at a time.